# Passing a template function as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have a generic list container that has a function find defined as follows:

```
template <class T>
typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>:: find(void * f, T data) {
    Iterator iterator;
    for (iterator = begin() ; iterator != end() ; iterator++) {
        if (f(*iterator, data)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return iterator;
}
```

So it takes a function f and an instance of type T and then iterates over the nodes in a list whose nodes 'contain' an instance of type T until one of them causes f(*iterator,data) to evaluate to true.
The dereference operator for iterator returns the data in the node so the types for iterator and data will be the same.

I'm trying to pass a function that would check if an object is in the list:

```
template <class T>
bool findByUnique(T compare, T data) {
    if (compare == data) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass the function as follows, but get the errors:

```
store.cpp:28:14: error: cannot resolve overloaded function âfindByUniqueâ based on conversion to type âvoid*â
store.cpp:29:56: error: expected primary-expression before â>â token
store.cpp:29:60: error: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
```

lines 27-29 (passing the function):

```
Album album(barcode,price,year,numPurchased,title,artist);
void * f = &findByUnique<Album>;
List<Album>::Iterator found = this->Albums->find<Album>(f,album);
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Searching on google indicates I have to apply static_cast to findByUnique but I'm not sure how it applies here.

Thanks.

Comment: it looks like `f` needs to be a function pointer, and not a void pointer

Comment: try using `typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>:: find(bool (*f)(T,T), T data)`

Comment: Thanks, I used a function pointer (as per Chris's link) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

@Taylor Flores is right. You aren't declaring your function pointer correctly in the declaration of find or for variable f. See (for example):

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: you're answer could benefit from a `c++` link instead and a example of function pointers with templates